# Why are trailing commas allowed in a list?

Tags: python, list, syntax

I am curious why in Python a trailing comma in a list is valid syntax, and it seems that Python simply ignores it:

```
>>> ['a','b',]
['a', 'b']
```

It makes sense when its a tuple since `('a')` and `('a',)` are two different things, but in lists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule

Comment: A trailing comma is also allowed in lists in C, C++, Java, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The main advantages are that it makes multi-line lists easier to edit and that it reduces clutter in diffs.

Changing:

```
s = ['manny',
     'mo',
     'jack',
]
```

to:

```
s = ['manny',
     'mo',
     'jack',
     'roger',
]
```

involves only a one-line change in the diff:

```
  s = ['manny',
       'mo',
       'jack',
+      'roger',
  ]
```

This beats the more confusing multi-line diff when the trailing comma was omitted:

```
  s = ['manny',
       'mo',
-      'jack'
+      'jack',
+      'roger'
  ]
```

The latter diff makes it harder to see that only one line was added and that the other line didn't change content.

It also reduces the risk of doing this:

```
s = ['manny',
     'mo',
     'jack'
     'roger'  # Added this line, but forgot to add a comma on the previous line
]
```

and triggering [implicit string literal concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842779/string-concatenation-without-operator-in-python), producing `s = ['manny', 'mo', 'jackroger']` instead of the intended result.

Comment: This makes the (most) sense, but I would really be surprised if the parser of the language was designed to make diffs easier.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Language designers are programmers, and programmers do many things to make their lives easier.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Not so much to make things easier for the diff program; rather, the goal is to make it easier for humans to make and review edits.

Comment: @Burhan If you don't believe that explanation, how about that it's also simpler to define the grammar that way? ;) Compare `List = "[" {Item ","} "]".` vs. `List = "[" ({Item","}Item|)"]".`

Comment: This also makes it easier for other programs to autogenerate code -- it's much easier to just print `"\"item\","` for each item than it is to print `"\"item\""` for each item followed by `","` for all but the last item.

Comment: …besides, I would usually forget to add the comma. Are there any compelling reasons _not_ to have it there?

Comment: @Voo I thought the same too but the latter grammar has to be defined anyway because it's still a valid Python list.

Comment: I think the `s = [` should be on its own line as well, in case the `'manny'` element needs to be changed.

Comment: Are there compelling reasons to use commas at all? Why disallow whitespace separation?

Comment: What is meant by `diff`, is this an abbreviation for `difference` or some fancy python-term I'm unaware of?

Comment: @AndreasL. I realize it's a bit late, but it means the [Unix utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Answer (score 42):

It's a common syntactical convention to allow trailing commas in an array, languages like C and Java allow it, and Python seems to have adopted this convention for its list data structure. It's particularly useful when generating code for populating a list: just generate a sequence of elements and commas, no need to consider the last one as a special case that shouldn't have a comma at the end.

Answer (score 39):

It helps to eliminate a certain kind of bug. It's sometimes clearer to write lists on multiple lines.
But in, later maintenace you may want to rearrange the items.

```
l1 = [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
]

# Now you want to rearrange

l1 = [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        5
        4,
]

# Now you have an error
```

But if you allow trailing commas, and use them, you can easily rearrange the lines without introducing an error.

Comment: This is neat, but you can avoid this by pre-pending the comma. I do that all the time when writing SQL

Comment: Even if you prepend the comma to each element, you still have to omit the comma on the first one.

Comment: A linter should be able to catch this, no?

Answer (score 6):

A tuple is different because `('a')` is expanded using implicit continuation and `()`s as a precendence operator, whereas `('a',)` refers to a length 1 tuple.

Your original example would have been `tuple('a')`

Comment: `('a'),` is a string; but my point was that trailing commas in tuples are significant, but in lists they don't appear to be yet Python accepts them.

Comment: They're silently discarded in both cases, it's just that in a tuple it's needed to differentiate it from a string in bracket.

Comment: `tuple('a')` is probably a bad example, because in general `tuple(x)` and `(x,)` are not the same thing. `tuple('ab') != ('ab',)`. `tuple('a') == ('a',)` only because `'a'` is a string of length 1.

Comment: From the REPL:
`>>> ("a",) == ("a")
       
`False

`>>> ("ab",) == ("ab")
       
`False

`>>> ("ab", "bc",) == ("ab", "bc")
       
`True

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is to make diff less complicated.
For example you have a list :

```
list = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
]
```

and you want to add another element to it. Then you will be end up doing this:

```
list = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd'
]
```

thus, diff will show that two lines have been changed, first adding ',' in line with 'c' and adding 'd' at last line.

So, python allows trailing ',' in last element of list, to prevent extra diff which can cause confusion.