# Python array combining

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to port some Python code to Java. I'm not familiar with Python and have never seen this in any language before:

```
return [c,] + s
```

What exactly does this line mean? Specifically the [c,] part. Is it combining two arrays or something? s is an array of integers and c is an integer. The full function is below (from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature )

```
def sign(self,m,z):
    self.permut(m)
    s,u = [None]*self.n,random.randint(0,self.q)
    c = v = self.E(u) 
    for i in range(z+1,self.n)+range(z):
        s[i] = random.randint(0,self.q)
        v = self.E(v^self.g(s[i],self.k[i].e,self.k[i].n)) 
        if (i+1)%self.n == 0: c = v
    s[z] = self.g(v^u,self.k[z].d,self.k[z].n)
    return [c,] + s
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma is redundant. It's just creating a one-element list:

```
>>> [1,]
[1]
>>> [1] == [1,]
True
```

The practice comes from creating *tuples* in Python; a one-element tuple requires a comma:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> (1) == (1,)
False
```

The `[c,] + s` statement creates a new list with the value of `c` as the first element.

Answer (score 3):

`[c,]` is exactly the same as `[c]`, i.e. a single-item list.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11597911/770830) for why this syntax is needed)

Answer (score 1):

For a list, the extra comma is redundant and can be ignored. The only time it makes a difference if it had been a tuple instead of a list so

```
[c,] and [c] are the same but,
(c,) and (c) are different. The former being a tuple and later just a parenthesis around an expression
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer both your questions, the line concatenates two lists, the first of the two is a one-element list since the comma is just ignored by python

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct, it is combining two "arrays" (lists in python).  If I'm not mistaken, the trailing comma is unnecessary in this instance.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1] + x

#is equivalent to

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,] + x
```

The reason Python allows the use of trailing commas in lists has to do with another data type called a tuple and ease of use with multi-line list declaration in code.

[Why does Python allow a trailing comma in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/trailing-comma-in-list-not-invalid-syntax)