# Concatenating strings using spaces?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I know you use "+" to concatenate strings like the following:

```
'foo' + 'bar'
```

Today I came across some code where it seems to concatenate strings using spaces(indentations) [**Update: wrong example, see Edit 2 below**]:

```
SQL = "select col1, col2 "
      "from table"
```

I didn't find this feature got mentioned in the book I'm reading or anywhere on the web. Can someone please explain to me that:

1. What does the space mean in this context? Why does it work?
2. When would you prefer spaces over "+"? For readability when concatenating strings span multiple lines?

Edit: Thank you for all your responses. After trying the code out myself it indeed didn't work. I probably missed some details when looking at the code before I left for work; so I'll check it out tomorrow. However, the following did work (and this made me assume the SQL example works without verifying first):

```
x = "foo" "bar"    # "foobar"
```

**Edit 2: It turned out that I missed a pair of parentheses in the SQL example above.** The actual code looks like this:

```
SQL = ("select col1, col2 "
       "from table")
```

Comment: Re: 1. It doesn't work. :)

Comment: Are you sure that was the exact code? Have a look at this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842779/string-concatenation-without-operator-in-python, which has a link to the docs regarding the rules around adjacent string literals.

Comment: The code would have to be `SQL = ("select col1, col2 "` on one line and `"from table")` on the next for that to work. This is because in general, two strings next to one another are automatically concatenated. The parenthesis around the expression defining `SQL` allow it to be split onto more than one line of code (like auto-continuation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation works automatically in python so there is no need for the `+` in your first example. You can do:

```
>>> "foo" "bar"
'foobar'
```

But if you want a space between foo and bar, either needs to be added to the end of one string or the beginning of the next.

```
>>> "foo " "bar"
'foo bar'
```

Parenthised expressions can extend to multiple lines. Once you open a paren, python knows to ignore newlines until you close it. So this also works

```
>>> ("foo"
... "bar")
'foobar'

>>> ("foo "
... "bar")
'foo bar'
```

And expressions in function calls can also have newlines

```
>>> def baz(sql=''):
...     print(sql)
... 
>>> baz(sql="foo "
...     "bar")
foo bar
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

> String literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes `'` or
>   double quotes `"`. They can also be enclosed in matching groups of
>   three single or double quotes (these are generally referred to as
>   triple-quoted strings). The backslash `\` character is used to escape
>   characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline,
>   backslash itself, or the quote character.

```
SQL = "select col1, col2 "
      "from table"
```

The above code is invalid; you need a backslash character:

```
SQL = "select col1, col2 "\
      "from table"
```

String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quoted strings:

```
s = """select col1, col2
      from table"""
```

But they're different, triple-quoted strings maybe give you extra whitespace, tabs and newlines.