# What's the usage to add a comma after self argument in a class method?

Tags: python

In the code I'm viewing, I saw some class method like this:

```
class A(B):

    def method1(self,):
        do_something

    def method2(self,):
        do_something_else
```

Why the writer leave a comma behind self, what's his/her purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

syntatically, the trailing comma [is allowed](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) but doesn't really mean anything.  This is pretty much just a stylistic preference.  I think that **most** python programmers would leave it off (which is the advice that I would also give) but a few might prefer it to make it so that it's easy to add more arguments later.

You can also [keep it in there when *calling* the function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).  You'll see this more often with functions which take lots of default arguments:

```
x = foo(
    arg1=whatever,
    arg2=something,
    arg3=blatzimuffin,
)
```

This works for lists and tuples too:

```
lst = [x, y, z,]
tup = (x, y, z)
tup = x,  # Don't even need parens for a tuple...
```

It's particularly nice if you want to format nested stuff nicely:

```
{
    "top": [
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "baz",
    ],
    "bottom": [
        "qux",
    ],
}
```

As when adding things to the list you just need to add/edit 1 line, not 2.

Comment: it's wired that some of his method has that comma, and some doesn't, it seems that he is intend to do so.

Comment: I would definitely leave it off. Cf.  [Trailing commas in python tuples.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/trailing-comma-in-list-not-invalid-syntax)

Comment: @Zen -- It's not that weird.  People are unfortunately inconsistent all the time ... Programmers aren't exempt :-)

Comment: "Easy" as in, doesn't have to check whether a comma needs to be added or not? I've seen similar things done in Ruby and the reason was also because it's "easier" but I never asked what was easier about it.

Comment: @MxyL -- It's one less character to type.  Again, I don't recommend this for function definitions.  formatted lists/tuples/dicts which span multiple lines can be kinda nice.

Comment: yes just do not ask internet explorer about a trailing comma in js :D

Comment: @sherpya -- Well, to be fair, that's a completely different language and AFAIK, the trailing comma isn't part of the ECMA script specification ...

Comment: yes a bit off topic and you are right but every other browser on earth is happy with trailing comma, except ie :)