# Final parentheses when calling functions with long argument lists

Tags: python, pep8

When calling function with long argument lists, should the closing parenthesis be on a separate line? For example:

```
import module1.module2

def main():

    # alternative 1, closing parenthesis on separate line
    x=3
    y=4
    my_result_name_1, my_result_name_2 = module1.module2.function3(
        argument_name1, argument_name2, keyword_argument=(x,y)
    )
    print(my_result_name_1)

    # alternative 2, closing parenthesis on same line as last argument
    x=3
    y=4
    my_result_name_1, my_result_name_2 = module1.module2.function3(
        argument_name1, argument_name2, keyword_argument=(x,y))
    print(my_result_name_1)

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The examples in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) are a little bit confusing to me. First they have this example:

```
# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

Then later, they have this:

```
my_list = [
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
]
```

Which style is preferred?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985688/indentation-of-closing-parenthesis

Comment: I'm pretty sure both styles are acceptable. I think closing parens on the same line look better on longer lines, whereas in a different line they are prettier on short ones.

Comment: I'd go for: 1) Always one argument per line, independently if it's long or not. 2) Closing parens in its own line. Why? Because in this way every time you change a single argument or add/remove a single argument this changes only that line and it's very easy to understand the `diff`s in VSCs.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the suggestion. I think I go with this! It makes the code more readable than the other alternatives, and prefer readability to conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, when I've only a need for a second additional line; I put the open and close brackets in-line, eg:

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_for)
```

But if I'm going to have more that one additional line, I keep the content on separate lines, eg:

```
my_list = [
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9
]
```

Really it is up to you to decide how you want to do it. For me, the most important things are readability and consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Looks good,  just one thing: According to PEP8: *"Arguments on first line are forbidden when not using vertical alignment"*. So your first example is not recommended according to PEP8?

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit vague. What has to be vertically aligned exactly? How would you align the in-line arguments vertically?

Comment: I edited your question to show how I would interpret the statement, just roll the edit back if you don't agree :)

Comment: I think I agree :) Definitely more readable than how I had it the first go round.