# Does a trailing comma after an n-tuple in Python change its value?

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a very basic doubt that came to my mind. When we use `threading` module in python to start a new thread, I have see two different ways in which arguments are passed to with the call:

**Version 1:**

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=tar,args=(4,0.25,))
```

**Version 2:**

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=tar,args=(4,0.25))
```

The difference is the addition of `,` at the end of argument list at the end of version 1 call. Both the versions work fine but I want to know if theres any significant difference between the two versions above and if than which ones a better way to write? If theres no difference than what is the reason a lot of people and articles choose to use version 1 and add a redundant `,` at the end of the argument list.

Comment: No, frequently you will see something like args=(4,) but rarely do people say args=(4, 0.25,).  The reason for the trailing comma is to flag to the compiler that the value being read is a tuple.  (4) just parses as 4, but (4,) is the tuple containing 4 as its only element.  (4, 0.25) is already a tuple.

Comment: It not only applies to tuples, but lists and dicts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-does-python-allow-a-trailing-comma-in-list for a reason

Comment: My thoughts on it not being idiomatic to see a trailing comma in a tuple declaration weren't *exactly* correct...I'd love to see an explanation that justifies the difference.  My stance remains:  I don't believe that there's a difference between the two function-wise.

Comment: @DarrenRinger so if I understand correct when you pass just one argument than you need a trailing comma so as to tell compiler that its a tuple but if you have more than 1 argument than you don't need trailing comma right?

Answer (score 2):

The two forms of writing a 2-tuple are equivalent.  Proof:

```
>>> (4,0.25,) == (4,0.25)
True
```

For an elaboration on valid tuple syntax in Python, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax.  Specifically:

> In Python, multiple-element tuples look like:
>
> 1,2,3
>
> The essential elements are the commas between each element of
>   the tuple. Multiple-element tuples may be written with a trailing
>   comma, e.g.
>
> 1,2,3,
>
> but the trailing comma is completely optional.