# Creating a list through multiplication

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

When playing with a code I have noticed that `[0,]*6`, does not return `[0,0,0,0,0,0,]` but rather `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`. Can you please explain why?

Comment: just give enter after `[0,]` in idle. It would print `[0]`

Comment: They're the same. The last comma is redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Python allow a trailing comma in list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-does-python-allow-a-trailing-comma-in-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[0,0,0,0,0,0,]` and `[0,0,0,0,0,0]` are the same lists. Last comma is acceptable by python syntax analyzer in order to distinguish a variable and a tuple with a variable inside: `(1)` is `int`, `(1,)` is `tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

`()` `(,)` is different 1st shows `value` and other is `tuple`, while in case of list `[]` and `[,]` both presentation is same.

```
In [4]: [0,]*6
Out[4]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [5]: [0]*6
Out[5]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [6]: (1,)*6
Out[6]: (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

In [7]: (1)*6
Out[7]: 6

In [8]: [0,] == [0]
Out[8]: True

In [9]: (0,) == (0)
Out[9]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists do not end with commas. It's just the way the syntax goes. However, Python will think the `('hello world')` to be a string. To make a tuple, you must end it with a comma `('hello world',)`. So, in your case, Python thought `[0,]` to be equivalent to `[0]`. It's just the way the syntax goes.