# namedtuple declaration indentation

Tags: python

I have the following `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Product = namedtuple(
        'Product',
        'product_symbol entity unique_id as_of_date company_name followers linkedin_employees linkedin industry date_added date_updated description website sector product_industry'
    )
```

What is the best way to declare it, so it does not exceeds the Python line limit of 80 characters?

Comment: There are implicit line-continuations inside of parentheses. Also, note that Python does implicit string-literal concatenation, so `'Hello ' 'world'` will implicitely become `'Hello world'`...

Comment: Are all those space-separated items in the string `'product_symbol entity unique_id as_of_date ...'` supposed to become separate elements/members of the `namedtuple`?

Comment: @martineau: `namedtuple` is documented to accept a space and/or comma separated string of the property names, or a sequence of strings where each string is a property name. Either one works; I tend to use the single string for brevity when it's half a dozen short names or fewer, but for a longer set of properties, moving to a `list`/`tuple` of `str` would probably improve readability.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I know that, I just want to understand what the OP wants done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose a PEP-8 compliant version which declares your attributes as a list.

```
name = 'Product'
attrs = [
   'product_symbol',
   'entity',
   'unique_id',
   ... 
]

Product = namedtuple(name, attrs)
```

Add a trailing comma to `attrs`, [this makes it easy when doing diff comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-are-trailing-commas-allowed-in-a-list).

Comment: You don't need to join, the second argument can be a sequence. The string version is for us lazy people :)

Answer (score 4):

If your version of Python is modern enough (Python 3.6+), you might consider a declarative version:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import NamedTuple

class Product(NamedTuple):
    product_symbol: str
    entity: str
    unique_id: int
    as_of_date: datetime
    company_name: str
    followers: list
    linkedin_employees: list
    linkedin: str
    industry: str
    date_added: datetime
    date_updated: datetime
    description: str
    website: str
    sector: str
    product_industry: str
```

The generated type is equivalent to a `collections.namedtuple`, but with `__annotations__` and `_field_types` attributes added.  The implementation detail is different:

- `namedtuple` is a factory function, it builds up a string defining the type and then uses [`exec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/301e3cc8a5bc68c5347ab6ac6f83428000d31ab2/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L397), returning the generated type.
- `NamedTuple` is a class, it uses [metaclasses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/301e3cc8a5bc68c5347ab6ac6f83428000d31ab2/Lib/typing.py#L1386) and a custom `__new__` to handle the annotations, and then [delegates to collections anyway](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/301e3cc8a5bc68c5347ab6ac6f83428000d31ab2/Lib/typing.py#L1336) to build the type (with the same code generation + `exec` as above).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Python's implicit joining of adjacent string literals to make it more readable and be PEP 8 compliant. Note I also added (optional) commas between items in the string which I think makes it even more readable.

```
Product = namedtuple('Product',
                     'product_symbol, entity, unique_id, as_of_date,'
                     'company_name, followers, linkedin_employees,'
                     'linkedin, industry, date_added, date_updated,'
                     'description, website, sector, product_industry')
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are only talking about breaking up the string so it does not exceed the 80 character limit you can use the \ character in a string so that it will be interpreted as single string without newlines(\n)

```
from collections import namedtuple

Product = namedtuple(
        'Product',
        'product_symbol entity unique_id as_of_date company_name followers\
         linkedin_employees linkedin industry date_added date_updated\ 
         description website sector product_industry'
    )
```