# Django Installed apps

Tags: django, settings

Why does Django installed apps end with a comma at the end eg

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'dj ango.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
]
```

Is the extra comma necessary?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the extra comma is not necessary. But allowing an extra comma makes life easier: It is easier to remove the last element of the array and easier to append a new element to the array if the final comma is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not necessary.

Check the following link:

[Why are trailing commas allowed in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-are-trailing-commas-allowed-in-a-list)