# why there is no error for a= [10,] but error for [10,,] in python?

Tags: python, list, syntax, syntax-error

why is there no error for `a = [10,]`  but error for `[10,,]` in Python ?
[image]
what is interpreter expecting from comma/s in both the cases?

I understand it's more of a syntax error but there has to rationale/logical explanation of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are trailing commas allowed in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-are-trailing-commas-allowed-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a logical explanation.

Many people, when writing a list, leave in the extra final comma, as in

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,]
```

So, Python allows that and ignores a final comma. But you can't have an empty entry in the MIDDLE of a list.

Comment: +1. Especially when they write their list vertically. *Black* also formats long lists vertically with a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

In python list we cannot have an empty entry in middle of two values. We need to put either any `value of any datatype` or `None.`

-->In this the pyhton will ignore the last comma as no value is after that.

```
lst = [10,20,30,]
```

--> It shows there is an empty entry before the end of list and its not permissible. Thats why it will throw an error.

```
lst = [10,,]
```