# Fastavro fails to parse Avro schema with enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, avro, fastavro

I have the following code block:

```
import fastavro

schema = {
    "name": "event",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [{"name": "event_type", "type": "enum", "symbols": ["START", "STOP"]}],
}

checker = fastavro.parse_schema(schema=schema)
```

Upon running it, it generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_schema.py", line 7, in <module>
    checker = fastavro.parse_schema(schema=schema)
  File "fastavro\_schema.pyx", line 121, in fastavro._schema.parse_schema
  File "fastavro\_schema.pyx", line 322, in fastavro._schema._parse_schema
  File "fastavro\_schema.pyx", line 381, in fastavro._schema.parse_field
  File "fastavro\_schema.pyx", line 191, in fastavro._schema._parse_schema
fastavro._schema_common.UnknownType: enum
```

I'm running fastavro 1.7.0, on Windows 10, and python 3.8.8.  I have had similar problems on Linux (RHEL 8) using python 3.10.

Based on the [Avro documentation for enumerated types](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.1/spec.html#Enums), the schema seems correct, but fastavro fails to recognize the `enum` type.  Am I doing something wrong here, or does fastavro 1.7.0 not support Avro 1.9 enumerations?

Comment: Did you accidentally leave a comma in the code example?

Comment: @СергейКох, I use the black formater, and it automatically inserted the comma; it's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the schema is not correctly formed.  After some additional checking, the following works:

```
import fastavro

schema = {
    "name": "event",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "event_type",
            "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "event_type_enums",
                "symbols": ["START", "STOP"],
            },
        }
    ],
}

checker = fastavro.parse_schema(schema=schema)
```

Comment: Please tell me why, when checking, the last three commas do not give valid json.

Comment: Ah, it's not JSON, it's a python dictionary.  Python allows trailing commas as shown. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-are-trailing-commas-allowed-in-a-list